# Проблема с расстановкой кавычек

Tags: php, html

Каким образом в `echo` записать html-код с привязкой к `onclick` функции со строковым параметром?

```
echo '<a href = "#" onclick = "func(''' . $a. ''', ''' . $b. ''')">' . $b. '</a>';
```

То есть, в `echo` используем одинарную кавычку, а в последующем html-коде - двойную. Но каким-то образом надо сделать так, чтобы переменные внутри функции `func` тоже заключались в кавычки. Если делать так, как на примере выше, то вылезает php-ошибка:

> syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для экранирования символов в PHP используют обратный слеш `\`.

Для вашего случая:

```
echo '<a href = "#" onclick = "func(\'' . $a. '\', \'' . $b. '\')">' . $b. '</a>';
```

Comment: Опередил меня)))

Answer (score 0):

Никаких кавычек расставлять не надо
И `echo` тоже не надо

```
?>
<a href = "#" onclick = "func('<?=$a?>', '<?=$b?>')"><?=$b?></a>
```

Comment: Если в вопросе указано, что делается именно через echo, значит, это вызвано какой-то необходимостью.